# Dropdown filtering

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the following code to populate dropdown boxes. This is a language I haven't explored much but it worked fairly well to what I wanted to do

```
<script>$(function() { 
                $("#exchangenameselect").change(function() {
                $("#jobnoselect").load("getter.php?choice=" + $.trim($("#exchangenameselect").val()).replace(' ', '+'));
                $("#wptable").empty();
                });

            });
   </script> 

   <script>$(function() { 
                $("#jobnoselect").change(function() {
                $("#wpselect").load("getter2.php?jobchoice=" + $.trim($("#jobnoselect").val()).replace(' ', '+'));
                $("#wptable").empty();
                });
                $("#wpselect").change(function() {
                $("#wptable").load("editjob2.php?wpchose=" + $("#wpselect").val());
                });
            });
   </script>
```

This code worked fine but now the database has entries under `wpchose` that have different values for `jobchoice` and displays them both. Not what I need.

How can I take the value of the last choice and incorporate it into the next function?

ie. `getter2.php?jobchoice=" + $.trim($("#jobnoselect").val()).replace(' ', '+') "&exchoice=" + $.trim($("#exchangenameselect").val()).replace(' ', '+'));`

and finally incorporate all three choices sent to editjob2.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>$(function() { 
                $("#exchangenameselect").change(function() {
                $("#jobnoselect").load("getter.php?choice=" + $.trim($("#exchangenameselect").val()).replace(' ', '+'));
                $("#wptable").empty();
                });

            });
   </script> 

   <script>$(function() { 
                $("#jobnoselect").change(function() {
                $("#wpselect").load("getter2.php?jobchoice=" + $("#jobnoselect").val());
                $("#wptable").empty();
                });
                $("#wpselect").change(function() {
                $("#wptable").load("editjob2.php?wpchose=" + $("#wpselect").val() + "&choice=" + $.trim($("#exchangenameselect").val()).replace(' ', '+') + "&jobchoice=" + $("#jobnoselect").val());
                });
            });
   </script>
```

Error in my use of language. Left up for reference for others